Does Blender's gltf exporter export Custom Properties that are on bones?
Blender's gltf exporter has an option to include Custom Properties when exporting under Include > Data > Custom Properties. It seems to work when the property is on a mesh, but not when it's on a bone. Has anyone else tried this and had any luck? It seems to me the exporter doesn't support Custom Properties on bones, only on meshes. I did a test export in .fbx and it was able to keep the Property.

I think I found the answer to this, basically gltf does write out custom properties on bones, but the custom property needs to be set on the bone in Object Mode and not Edit or Pose Mode. That was my fix, at least.
